# How to obtain a dictionary from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataframe consisting 2 columns. One column is made from names and the other represent some numeric values. The names can be the same. I would like to take the mean of the values of each names and put them in a list,dictionary or again a dataframe.

I have tried to transfer all names and numeric values to a dictionary as keys and values respectively. However, a dictionary can no have a duplicate keys.

```
measurement_df = pd.read_csv('2019-6-9-Measurement.csv')
mac_rssi_df=measurement_df[['MacAddress','Rssi']]
rssi_df=measurement_df[['Rssi']]
rssi_list=rssi_df.values.tolist()
mac_list=measurement_df[['MacAddress']].values.tolist()
x=0
while x<424627  :
    rssi_list[x] = rssi_list[x][0]
    mac_list[x]=mac_list[x][0]
    x=x+1
dict_mac_rssi=dict(zip(mac_list,rssi_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
mac_rssi_df.to_dict()
```

more info in [official site](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)